# cant activate virtual env through vs windows 11 python 3.10.4

Tags: python, python-venv

Was just trying out making an environment via python and Django, but i keep running into this issue where the python interpreter does not seem to understand.

I have use `source bin/activate` as well, but to no avail.

```
.\test.com_env\Scripts\activate.ps1 : 

The term '.\test.com_env\Scripts\activate.ps1' is not recognized 
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
.\test.com_env\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

Comment: error suggest to check if exists file `.\test.com_env\Scripts\activate.ps1`. Did  you check it? Maybe you deleted it or you renamed it. If you can't find it then you may have to create new environment and move code to new environment

Comment: important question: what type of terminal are you using?  Are you in PowerShell? Command Prompt?  A Git Bash terminal? The command needed is slightly different in each setup, in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem on Windows 10. My solution was: From the outer folder to the virtual environment folder, I performed the following command line:

You can try:

> .\test.com_env\Scripts\activate

I didn't have to add the extension.ps1.

You should check the location from where the above command line is being executed.

Comment: I believe he's working on linux where he gets bin folder instead of scripts.

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code.